# Guacamole Disconnect Session on User Idle

Tags: guacamole

I have google'ed a lot on this question but haven't found an answer. I have a Guacamole server that connects to a local VNC session and I would like for it to disconnect the user session if it detects no activity for an hour.

**What I've tried and attempted**

- used xprintidle to show idle time of the user, this works so will be put in a script that might be used later to terminate an idle session.
- I have looked at Guacamole's api-session-timeout and set it for a minute, I had hoped it would not reconnect to the same session once the VNC server stops abruptly. It seems this did not work.
- I have tried to use guacamole's user-mappings.xml to specify the parameter "autoretry" and set that to "1". Restarted and this did not work, I'm thinking its not used this way.
- I have went to the guacamole postgres database and manually inserted the entry for autoretry into the parameter table. Restarted, but this did not work.
- I have went to the VNC side (I use TurboVNC) and looked at the flag -idletimeout and configuration option max-idle-timeout. This terminates the TurboVNC service when there are no active connections. It is not what I am after, I'm trying to only disconnect the session when the user is idle.

I figured that the VNC side would not work because even if the VNC session is terminated Guacamole would keep on retying forever to reconnect to that session.

From some posts on the Guacamole mailing list it seems that disabling auto reconnect is not possible without a recompile from source.

Is there a way to disconnect an active session after an idle timeout period? or maybe a way to stop Guacamole from reconnecting?